# Monotouch 6.0.2: Why cannot serialize the object when using WCF services

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

I use the WCF with BasicHttpBinding in monotouch(6.0.2) to consume the .net WCF Service,
I pass 3 parameters which the type is int,int, DishOrder(user-defined type), in the server site, it can read the int parameters correctly, but the user-defined object(dishOrder) is always null, why?

I have already used the [DataContract] attribute mark in the user-defined type class.

in monotouch (client side code:)

```
[DataContract]
public class DishOrder2
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BillID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TableID { get; set; }
}

public partial interface IMenuContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    int OpenTable(int tableID, int lastVerNo,DishOrder2 order);
}

public partial class MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IMenuContract>,IMenuContract  {
    public int OpenTable(int tableID, int lastVerNo,DishOrder2 order)
    {
        return Channel.OpenTable(tableID,lastVerNo,order);
    }   

    private partial class FDMenuServiceClientChannel
    {
        public  int OpenTable(int tableID, int lastVerNo,DishOrder2 order)
        {
            object[] _args = new object[3];

            _args[0]=tableID;
            _args[1]=lastVerNo;
            _args[2]=order;
            return (int)base.Invoke("OpenTable", _args);
        }
    }
} //end of public partial class FDMenuServiceClient 



   pulic void CallServiceTest()
  {
            using (MyServiceClient.serviceClient = MyServiceClient.CreateServiceClient ()) {
                  DishOrder2 test=new DishOrder2();
            test.BillID=123;
            test.TableID=456;
                serviceClient.OpenTable(111,222,test);
            }
  }
```

in service site(.net 3.5) code:

```
[DataContract]
public class DishOrder2
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BillID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int TableID { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
int OpenTable(int tableID, int lastVerNo,DishOrder2 order);

    public int OpenTable(int tableID, int lastVerNo,DishOrder2 dishOrder)  //service implementation
    {
        try
        {
            //**---why the object:dishorder is null?** throw the nullref exception
            if (dishOrder.BillID>0)  ...                  
            //**tableID & lastVerNo is read OK 111,222**  
                  ...             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw FaultException...            
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cannot found the reason why cannot serialize the object automatic in monotouch, So I have to do serialization myself. It can work now, thanks all.

```
    public static string XmlSerialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```